# Script is not working

Tags: javascript, php

In my PHP generated webpage there are 3 linked listboxes. When the user changes the selection in list_1, the contents of list_2 and list_3 changes accordingly (e.g. as it would change in 3 lists containing **`continent -> country -> city`**).

The code is:

PHP (032A_GetProvincie.php) [EDITED]

```
$provincie = array();

$query = 'SELECT nume_prov FROM sa_Provincie ';
$query .= 'WHERE provincie_id > 777 ';
$query .= 'ORDER BY nume_prov';

// Get query ---------------------------------------------------

$query_data = mysqli_query($db_conn, $query);

if ($query_data == FALSE)
   {
   array_push($provincie, 'None found');
   goto _adr1;
   }

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_data);
if ($rows == 0)
   {
   array_push($provincie, 'None found');
   goto _adr1;
   }

// Build array -------------------------------------------------

array_push($provincie, 'All_';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_data))
      array_push($provincie, $row['nume_prov']);

// End 

_adr1:
print json_encode($provincie);

mysqli_free_result($query_data);
mysqli_close($db_conn);
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$.getJSON("/scripts/032A_GetProvincie.php", function(data)
   {
   var str_options = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
       {
       str_options += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option> \r\n";
       }

   $("#listaProvincie").append(str_options);

   $("#listaProvincie").change();
   });


$("#listaProvincie").change(function()
{
$.getJSON("/scripts/032B_GetRegiune.php?provincie=" + $(this).val(), function(data)
   {
   var str_options = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
       {
       str_options += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option> \r\n";
       }

   $("#listaRegiune").html("");
   $("#listaRegiune").append(str_options);

   $("#listaRegiune").change();

   });
});
...
```

listaProvincie is list_1, listaRegiune is list_2, etc. When data is returned by the PHP queries, the lists are populated accordingly;

**however**, if the query there returns no data, the line 'None found' does not appear as an option in list_1, the list remains BLANK.

I am a Javascript rookie, so maybe I do not understand something elementary, but what is wrong with my code ? And please don't try to give me a solution that uses Ajax, I know almost nothing about it.

Note: In the code I show here, the WHERE clause of my PHP query deliberately contains a condition `provincie_id > 777` that I know returns no rows, yet list_1 remains blank. I am thinking, any value I push in the array should appear in the list, shouldn't it ?

[EDIT 1] No, it's not right. When I push values directly into $provincie (PHP array), the script doesn't work anymore. Why ??? How can I give some feedback to the primary PHP page, which calls the JavaScript script, which calls 032A_GetProvincie.php, if something goes wrong in 032A_.. ?

[EDIT 2] I don't know exactly why, but after some more fidgeting, array_push() "started" working the way it should work, and my problems were solved. I'm a PHP ROOKIE as well. Well, I started programming in PHP 9 months ago, coming from VisualStudio. There, things are much more simple and clear.

Comment: Are you sure the query is succeeding? Maybe it's failing so the `if ($query_data == FALSE)` is executing, and it's sending back an empty result. Try adding `array_push($provincie, mysqli_error($db_conn))` in that case.

Comment: I added `array_push($provincie, 'None found');` in the `if ($query_data == FALSE) ` and nothing happens. With the condition I was mentioning in Note: at the end of my questions, I KNOW the query does not succeed, but you are right, the code needed a change. That bit of code actually checked if a connection is established, I changed it here.

Comment: Look at the raw response in the Network tab of the developer console.

Comment: You mean in the Mozilla Firefox Debugger ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean (if you're using Firefox).

Comment: It cycles me inside jquery.1.12.0.min.js.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. The Network tab should show the AJAX call to the PHP script. Then you select the Response tab to see what it returned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132003/discussion-between-mikey-and-barmar).

Comment: I EDITED my question, please look at the bottom of it.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of the script. Then use the Network tab to see the raw response, and check if there are any PHP error messges there.

Comment: If my query does not return any rows, obviously nothing will be displayed in the **listbox**, so I should figure out a way to put some info into it so that it DOESN'T remain empty.  This is what I actually asked in the first place. I do not get errors, now that I gave up pushing.

Comment: Your code already does that, by putting `None found` in the response. But something is not working correctly, you need to check the PHP error messages.

Comment: I think JSON does not like the way I put the messages in the array, even though I use array_push(). I now try to print the array with normal results in a parallel page to take a look at its contents and format.

Comment: `json_encode()` creates proper JSON. What's probably happening is that the script is printing something else in addition to the JSON, and that's causing the problem. Try putting the URL of the script into the Firefox address bar, then you'll see the whole response.

Comment: I used the push_array() in a "normal" page, i printed the array with print_r() and it looks ok ! (no error). Now I'll try to do what you suggested.

Comment: The result looks PERFECT: **["None_Start","Moldova","Transilvania","Transilvania de N","Transilvania de S","None_Stop"]**. Printed with **print json_encode**. I added None_Start & None_End with array_push().

Comment: Then I'm not sure why `$.getJSON` isn't working.

Comment: I am ashamed to tell you, but NOW it works. **I don't know why.** It seems I have wasted your time, and I apologize for that. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Barmar By suggesting to me to put the URL of the subordinated PHP script (i.e. 032A_GetProvincie.php) into a Browser page, you pointed me towards an excellent method to debug such scripts and get rid of any and all errors. It never occured to me to do that (incredibly stupid - I know). Previously I only copied the query into phpMySQL and ran it to see if it's correct. But your suggestion yelds much better results. Everything works fine now. Thanks again very much !